# How can I see all of the current per-site "Featured on Meta" posts?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, featured-tag

I often find that ideas on one site's meta are useful for other sites.  However, I often only discover them years later because I don't frequent every meta site.  Hence...

**Question**: How can I see all of the current per-site "Featured on Meta" posts?

I really have no idea how to see all of these at once, without e.g. going through the sites one by one.  I didn't find a data explorer query for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for a single site, you can go to ["[meta site url]/tags/featured"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/featured) or  ["[meta site url]/questions/tagged/featured"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured).

For all sites, specifically for all meta sites, you can use filtered search function on the general StackExchange.com page with the rules selected like so:

[image: Screenshot: "1. Which questions do you want to include? [x] Just questions with the [featured] tag on... [x] All meta sites ([x] show meta sites)"]

Note that this will also display localized names of the featured tag on other language metas, which might seem unusual, but this is exactly the result we want here.

Comment: Great!  Thanks!  By the way, filtered searches can be shared.  In this case: [Per-site meta: featured questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters/385458/per-site-meta-featured-questions)

Comment: Oh, I tried visiting my own share url for the filter in private browsing mode, but it gave me 404 so I assumed it's only accessible by the creator. Oh well :p